# BigQuery job filter by label

Tags: google-bigquery, command-line-interface

Is there any way to filter big query jobs with label(s)?

I created a job(query) with label `task_id:my_task`

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --label "task_id:my_task"  --project my-project 'SELECT * FROM `dataset.mytable`'
```

Tried those to get all jobs with the label but none of them worked:

```
bq ls -j --filter 'configuration.labels(task_id):my_task'
bq ls -j --filter 'configuration.labels.task_id:my_task'
bq ls -j --filter  configuration.labels(task_id):my_task
bq ls -j --filter  labels.task_id:my_task
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for "bq ls" [1], --filter lists datasets that match the filter expression. But for listing jobs, the documentation [2] mentions that the allowed flags are three: -j, -a and -n.

So, there isn't a way to filter the listing of jobs, at least through the Bigquery command tool. But as a workaround, you can use the following command to get all the Jobs that are labeled as "task_id:my_task"

```
for i in $(bq ls -j | awk 'NR>2 {print $1}'); do echo "$(bq show -j $i) $i" | awk '/task_id:my_task/ && /SUCCESS/ {print $(NF)}'; done
```

This command may take some time, though; so consider adding the -n flag like this:

```
for i in $(bq ls -j -n 10 | awk 'NR>2 {print $1}'); do echo "$(bq show -j $i) $i" | awk '/task_id:my_task/ && /SUCCESS/ {print $(NF)}'; done
```

You may also submit a feature request to the BigQuery's Issue Tracker [3].

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_ls

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#listing_jobs

[3] https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1100108